# How to fix TSparseArray<T>?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe7

Because of an unfixed bug with `System.Generics.Collections.TArray.Copy<T>` (depending on [already reported bug in `System.CopyArray`](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9620)) there will sometimes raise an exception using the threading library.

The exception is raised in method `System.Threading.TSparseArray<T>.Add`:

```
function TSparseArray<T>.Add(const Item: T): Integer;
var
  I: Integer;
  LArray, NewArray: TArray<T>;
begin
  ...
          TArray.Copy<T>(LArray, NewArray, I + 1); // <- Exception here
  ...
end;
```

Well that is expected with the bug in `System.CopyArray`. So when trying to fix this my first thought was to simply copy the array with:

```
// TArray.Copy<T>(LArray, NewArray, I + 1); // <- Exception here
for LIdx := Low( LArray ) to High( LArray ) do
  NewArray[LIdx] := LArray[LIdx];
```

Works like a charm. But after that I was wondering, why the array copy is needed:

```
LArray := FArray; // copy array reference from field
...
SetLength(NewArray, Length(LArray) * 2);
TArray.Copy<T>(LArray, NewArray, I + 1);
NewArray[I + 1] := Item;
Exit(I + 1);
```

The elements are copied to `NewArray` (local variable) and thats it. There is no assignment back to `FArray`, so to me the `NewArray` will be finalized when out of scope.

Now I have three bugfix choices:

1. Just replace `TArray.Copy`

   ```
   SetLength(NewArray, Length(LArray) * 2);
   // TArray.Copy<T>(LArray, NewArray, I + 1); // <- Exception here
   for LIdx := Low( LArray ) to High( LArray ) do
     NewArray[LIdx] := LArray[LIdx];
   NewArray[I + 1] := Item;
   Exit(I + 1);
   ```
2. Replace `TArray.Copy` and save `NewArray`

   ```
   SetLength(NewArray, Length(LArray) * 2);
   // TArray.Copy<T>(LArray, NewArray, I + 1); // <- Exception here
   for LIdx := Low( LArray ) to High( LArray ) do
     NewArray[LIdx] := LArray[LIdx];
   NewArray[I + 1] := Item;
   FArray := NewArray;
   Exit(I + 1);
   ```
3. Comment out all the unnecessary code parts (because they are just wasting time)

   ```
   // SetLength(NewArray, Length(LArray) * 2);
   // TArray.Copy<T>(LArray, NewArray, I + 1); // <- Exception here
   // NewArray[I + 1] := Item;
   Exit(I + 1);
   ```

I checked all three fixes with a bunch of tasks looking for unused worker threads or not executed tasks. But I did not find any of them. The library works as expected (and now without any exception).

**Can you please point me to what I am missing here?**

---

To get to this exception, you have run a bunch of tasks and let the `TTaskPool` create more and more `TWorkerQueueThreads`. Check the count of threads by TaskManager and use a breakpoint on `TArray.Copy` line in `TSparseArray<T>.Add` method. Here I get this exception when the thread count of the application goes beyond 25 threads.

```
// Hit the button very fast until the debugger stops 
// at TSparseArray<T>.Add method to copy the array
procedure TForm1.Button1Click( Sender : TObject );
var
  LIdx : Integer;
begin
  for LIdx := 1 to 20 do
    TTask.Run( 
      procedure 
      begin
        Sleep( 50 );
      end );
end;
```

Comment: Even if `TArray.Copy()` were fixed, I would think the missing assignment/modification of `FArray` would be a separate bug that also needs to be fixed. Otherwise how is `Add()` adding the `Item` to the array? I have not looked at `TSparseArray`'s source code yet.

Comment: `TSparseArray<T>` is weird. Why does it feel the need to create a separate lock object? What's wrong with locking itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter if the items are written to `TSparseArray<T>`, because it is only needed if a worker thread has finished all of the tasks delegated to him and another worker thread has not finished yet. At this point the idle thread is looking at the queues of the other treads inside the pool and tries to steal some work.

If any queue did not get into this array there are not visible to the idle threads and therefore the working load cannot be shared.

**To fix that I choose option 2**

```
function TSparseArray<T>.Add(const Item: T): Integer;
...
SetLength(NewArray, Length(LArray) * 2);
TArray.Copy<T>(LArray, NewArray, I + 1); // <- No Exception here with XE7U1
NewArray[I + 1] := Item;
{$IFDEF USE_BUGFIX}
FArray := NewArray;
{$ENDIF}
Exit(I + 1);
```

But that stealing part is risky implemented without any locking

```
procedure TThreadPool.TQueueWorkerThread.Execute;

...

if Signaled then
begin
  I := 0;
  while I < Length(ThreadPool.FQueues.Current) do
  begin
    if (ThreadPool.FQueues.Current[I] <> nil) 
      and (ThreadPool.FQueues.Current[I] <> WorkQueue)
      and ThreadPool.FQueues.Current[I].TrySteal(Item) 
    then
      Break;
    Inc(I);
  end;
  if I <> Length(ThreadPool.FQueues.Current) then
    Break;
  LookedForSteals := True;
end
```

The array length is only growing so

```
while I < Length(ThreadPool.FQueues.Current) do
```

and

```
if I <> Length(ThreadPool.FQueues.Current) then
```

should be safe enough.

```
if Signaled then
begin
  I := 0;
  while I < Length(ThreadPool.FQueues.Current) do
  begin
    {$IFDEF USE_BUGFIX}
    TMonitor.Enter(ThreadPool.FQueues);
    try
    {$ENDIF}
      if (ThreadPool.FQueues.Current[I] <> nil) and (ThreadPool.FQueues.Current[I] <> WorkQueue) and ThreadPool.FQueues.Current[I].TrySteal(Item) then
        Break;
    {$IFDEF USE_BUGFIX}
    finally
      TMonitor.Exit(ThreadPool.FQueues);
    end;
    {$ENDIF}
    Inc(I);
  end;
  if I <> Length(ThreadPool.FQueues.Current) then
    Break;
  LookedForSteals := True;
end
```

Now we need a test environment to watch the stealing:

```
program WatchStealingTasks;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Threading,
  System.Classes,
  System.Math;

procedure OutputDebugStr( const AStr: string ); overload;
begin
  OutputDebugString( PChar( AStr ) );
end;

procedure OutputDebugStr( const AFormat: string; const AParams: array of const ); overload;
begin
  OutputDebugStr( Format( AFormat, AParams ) );
end;

function CreateInnerTask( AThreadId: Cardinal; AValue: Integer; APool: TThreadPool ): ITask;
begin
  Result := TTask.Run(
      procedure
    begin
      Sleep( AValue );
      if AThreadId <> TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID
      then
        OutputDebugStr( '[%d] executed stolen task from [%d]', [TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID, AThreadId] )
      else
        OutputDebugStr( '[%d] executed task', [TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID] );
    end, APool );
end;

function CreateTask( AValue: Integer; APool: TThreadPool ): ITask;
begin
  Result := TTask.Run(
    procedure
    var
      LIdx: Integer;
      LTasks: TArray<ITask>;
    begin
      // Create three inner tasks per task
      SetLength( LTasks, 3 );
      for LIdx := Low( LTasks ) to High( LTasks ) do
        begin
          LTasks[LIdx] := CreateInnerTask( TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID, AValue, APool );
        end;
      OutputDebugStr( '[%d] waiting for tasks completion', [TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID] );
      TTask.WaitForAll( LTasks );
      OutputDebugStr( '[%d] task finished', [TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID] );
    end, APool );
end;

procedure Test;
var
  LPool: TThreadPool;
  LIdx: Integer;
  LTasks: TArray<ITask>;
begin
  OutputDebugStr( 'Test started' );
  try
    LPool := TThreadPool.Create;
    try
      // Create three tasks
      SetLength( LTasks, 3 );
      for LIdx := Low( LTasks ) to High( LTasks ) do
        begin
          // Let's put some heavy work (200ms) on the first tasks shoulder
          // and the other tasks just some light work (20ms) to do
          LTasks[LIdx] := CreateTask( IfThen( LIdx = 0, 200, 20 ), LPool );
        end;
      TTask.WaitForAll( LTasks );
    finally
      LPool.Free;
    end;
  finally
    OutputDebugStr( 'Test completed' );
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    Test;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln( E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message );
  end;
  ReadLn;

end.
```

And the debug log is

```
Debug-Ausgabe: Test started Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Thread-Start: Thread-ID: 2104. Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Thread-Start: Thread-ID: 2188. Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Thread-Start: Thread-ID: 4948. Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Debug-Ausgabe: [2188] waiting for tasks completion Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Debug-Ausgabe: [2104] waiting for tasks completion Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Thread-Start: Thread-ID: 2212. Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Debug-Ausgabe: [4948] waiting for tasks completion Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Debug-Ausgabe: [2188] executed task Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Debug-Ausgabe: [4948] executed task Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Debug-Ausgabe: [2188] executed task Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Debug-Ausgabe: [4948] executed task Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Debug-Ausgabe: [2188] executed task Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Debug-Ausgabe: [2188] task finished Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Debug-Ausgabe: [4948] executed task Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Debug-Ausgabe: [4948] task finished Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Debug-Ausgabe: [2104] executed task Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Debug-Ausgabe: [2188] executed stolen task from [2104] Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Debug-Ausgabe: [4948] executed stolen task from [2104] Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Debug-Ausgabe: [2104] task finished Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Debug-Ausgabe: Thread Exiting: 2188 Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Debug-Ausgabe: Thread Exiting: 4948 Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Thread-Ende: Thread-ID: 4948. Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Thread-Ende: Thread-ID: 2188. Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
Thread-Ende: Thread-ID: 2212. Prozess WatchStealingTasks.exe (4532)
```

Ok, stealing should be working now with any number of worker threads, so everything is alright?

**No**

This small test application will not come to an end, because now it freezes inside the destructor of the thread pool. The last worker thread will not terminate caused by

```
procedure TThreadPool.TQueueWorkerThread.Execute;

...

if ThreadPool.FWorkerThreadCount = 1 then
begin
  // it is the last thread after all tasks executed, but
  // FQueuedRequestCount is still on 7 - WTF
  if ThreadPool.FQueuedRequestCount = 0 then
  begin
```

One more bug to fix here ... because when waiting for tasks with `Task.WaitForAll` then all of the tasks you are now waiting for, were executed internally but will not decrease the `FQueuedRequestCount`.

Fixing that

```
function TThreadPool.TryRemoveWorkItem(const WorkerData: IThreadPoolWorkItem): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (QueueThread <> nil) and (QueueThread.WorkQueue <> nil);
  if Result then
    Result := QueueThread.WorkQueue.LocalFindAndRemove(WorkerData);
  {$IFDEF USE_BUGFIX}
  if Result then
    DecWorkRequestCount;
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

and now it runs like it should have done at once.

---

**Update**

As a comment by Uwe we also need to fix the fixed `System.Generics.Collections.TArray.Copy<T>`

```
class procedure TArray.Copy<T>(const Source, Destination: array of T; SourceIndex, DestIndex, Count: NativeInt);
{$IFDEF USE_BUGFIX}
begin
  CheckArrays(Pointer(@Source[0]), Pointer(@Destination[0]), SourceIndex, Length(Source), DestIndex, Length(Destination), Count);
  if IsManagedType(T) then
    System.CopyArray(Pointer(@Destination[DestIndex]), Pointer(@Source[SourceIndex]), TypeInfo(T), Count)
  else
    System.Move(Pointer(@Source[SourceIndex])^,Pointer(@Destination[DestIndex])^, Count * SizeOf(T) );
end;
{$ELSE}
begin
  CheckArrays(Pointer(@Source[0]), Pointer(@Destination[0]), SourceIndex, Length(Source), DestIndex, Length(Destination), Count);
  if IsManagedType(T) then
    System.CopyArray(Pointer(@Destination[SourceIndex]), Pointer(@Source[SourceIndex]), TypeInfo(T), Count)
  else
    System.Move(Pointer(@Destination[SourceIndex])^, Pointer(@Source[SourceIndex])^, Count * SizeOf(T));
end;
{$ENDIF}
```

A simple check to test:

```
procedure TestArrayCopy;
var
  LArr1, LArr2: TArray<Integer>;
begin
  LArr1 := TArray<Integer>.Create( 10, 11, 12, 13 );
  LArr2 := TArray<Integer>.Create( 20, 21 );
  // copy the last 2 elements from LArr1 to LArr2
  TArray.Copy<Integer>( LArr1, LArr2, 2, 0, 2 );
end;
```

- with XE7 you will get an exception
- with XE7 Update1 you will get

  ```
  LArr1 = ( 10, 11, 0, 0 )
  LArr2 = ( 20, 21 )
  ```
- with that fix above will get

  ```
  LArr1 = ( 10, 11, 12, 13 )
  LArr2 = ( 12, 13 )
  ```

Comment: The takeaway from all of this is that the code is not currently trustworthy. When are Emba going to hire some developers that have the ability to write correct multi-threaded code? This is `TMonitor` all over again.

Comment: Yes most time we will see good ideas bad implemented and not really tested or tested on the wrong platform or just an "it compiles" test.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a bug in `System.CopyArray`. By design it only supports managed types. The bug is in fact in `TArray.Copy<T>`. That is mistaken in calling `System.CopyArray` without discriminating on whether or not `T` is a managed type.

However, the latest version of `TArray.Copy<T>`, from XE7 update 1 does not appear to suffer from the problem you describe. The code looks like this:

```
class procedure TArray.Copy<T>(const Source, Destination: array of T; 
  SourceIndex, DestIndex, Count: NativeInt);
begin
  CheckArrays(Pointer(@Source[0]), Pointer(@Destination[0]), SourceIndex, 
    Length(Source), DestIndex, Length(Destination), Count);
  if IsManagedType(T) then
    System.CopyArray(Pointer(@Destination[SourceIndex]), 
      Pointer(@Source[SourceIndex]), TypeInfo(T), Count)
  else
    System.Move(Pointer(@Destination[SourceIndex])^, Pointer(@Source[SourceIndex])^, 
      Count * SizeOf(T));
end;
```

Unless I am mistaken in my analysis, you simply need to apply update 1 to resolve the problems with `System.CopyArray`.

---

But as Uwe points out in comments below, this code is still bogus. It uses `SourceIndex` erroneously where `DestIndex` should be used. And the source and destination parameters are passed in the wrong order. One also wonders why the author wrote `Pointer(@Destination[SourceIndex])^` rather than `Destination[SourceIndex]`. I find this whole situation terribly depressing. How can Embarcadero release code of such appalling quality?

---

Deeper than the above are the problems with `TSparseArray<T>`. Which looks like this:

```
function TSparseArray<T>.Add(const Item: T): Integer;
var
  I: Integer;
  LArray, NewArray: TArray<T>;
begin
  while True do
  begin
    LArray := FArray;
    TMonitor.Enter(FLock);
    try
      for I := 0 to Length(LArray) - 1 do
      begin
        if LArray[I] = nil then
        begin
          FArray[I] := Item;
          Exit(I);
        end else if I = Length(LArray) - 1 then
        begin
          if LArray <> FArray then
            Continue;
          SetLength(NewArray, Length(LArray) * 2);
          TArray.Copy<T>(LArray, NewArray, I + 1);
          NewArray[I + 1] := Item;
          Exit(I + 1);
        end;
      end;
    finally
      TMonitor.Exit(FLock);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The only time `FArray` is initialized is in the `TSparseArray<T>` constructor. This means that if the array becomes full, then items are added and lost. Presumably the `I = Length(LArray) - 1` is meant to extend the length of `FArray` and capture the new item. However, note also that `TSparseArray<T>` exposes `FArray` through the `Current` property. And this exposure is not protected by the lock. So, I cannot see how this class can behave in any useful way once `FArray` becomes full.

I suggest that you construct an example where `FArray` becomes full an demonstrate that items which are added are lost. Submit a bug report demonstrating that, and linking to this question.

Comment: That does not *really fix* `TSparseArray<T>`. The exception will not raise any more and everything *seems* to be fine, but the weird and useless copy is still there and leaves a bad smell. I'll try to dig more into the code why it works without all the copy part.

Comment: BTW You are indeed right, that `System.CopyArray` works as documented. My fault was the same as the writer of `TArray.Copy<T>` - believing/assuming instead of knowing/reading the docs :o)

Comment: @SirRufo I think it's much deeper than this. It's not enough to use option 2 in your question because `FArray` is exposed publicly without a lock. I think there's no easy fix for us to apply, not least because we cannot really know the design of this class. Personally I expect it to take Emba about 5 years to fix this new threading library, just as it took them that long to fix `TMonitor`. I don't believe that they have the skill to write a clean threading library.

Comment: The code for TArray.Copy<T> has several bugs: 1. The call to System.CopyArray uses SourceIndex for the destination as well as the call to System.Move does and 2. the call to System.Move messes up source and destination. This makes TArray.Copy<T> almost unusable for quite a lot situations.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan *`Pointer(@Destination[SourceIndex])^` rather than `Destination[SourceIndex]`* because you cannot ... `Source` and `Destination` are `const` arguments and you must go that way or change the method arguments into `var`

Comment: @SirRufo OK, yet another appalling mistake! `Destination` should be `var`. Note that `Source` is fine as `const`.

Comment: The real bugger with the System.Move call is that the first parameter should be Source and the second Destination. As of now it is simply overwriting the source array for non-managed types.

Comment: @UweRaabe Yes, I see that now. It's quite amazing how bad this code is!

Comment: See the last update at the end of my answer adressing that copy method

Comment: @SirRufo There's more wrong than just that. I'm thinking of the use of const for a parameter that is modified. I submitted a bug report: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9887 and that report contains code that I think is correct.